# coupled vectors in spherical coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, vectors, spherical-harmonics

I have asked a similar question before ([Coordinates for coupled transition dipole moments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578781/coordinates-for-coupled-transition-dipole-moments)). What I am trying to do here is to write the $X$ component of $\vec{\mu}_{\beta}$, which is $\sin(\theta_{Z\beta})\cos(\phi_{\beta})$ as a function of $\theta_{Z\alpha}$,$\phi_{\alpha}$, $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\phi_{\alpha\beta} = \phi_{\alpha} - \phi_{\beta}$ (I am not 100% sure of this last relation I wrote). In other words, I need to get rid of $\theta_{Z\beta}$,$\phi_{\beta}$ in my equation, so that I can just integrate it over the coordinates of $\vec{\mu}_{\alpha}$. Extra information is that the internal angle $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$ is fixed, it can thus be treated as a constant.

I tried to use the formula for dot products in spherical coordinates (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243142/what-is-the-general-formula-for-calculating-dot-and-cross-products-in-spherical), plug in an expression for $\cos(\theta_{Z\beta})$ written in terms of spherical harmonics, as a function of $\theta_{Z\alpha}$,$\phi_{\alpha}$, $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\phi_{\alpha\beta}$ and solve for $\sin(\theta_{Z\beta})$, but it does not seem to work.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: "write the $X$ component of $\vec{\mu}_{\beta}$ as a function of $\theta_{Z\alpha}$,$\phi_{\alpha}$, $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\phi_{\alpha\beta} = \phi_{\alpha} - \phi_{\beta}$" -- this is not possible to do uniquely. You basically know $\vec\mu_\alpha$ from $\theta_{Z\alpha}$ and $\phi_{\alpha}$. Knowing $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\phi_{\alpha\beta}$ gives you, respectively, a cone around $\vec\mu_\alpha$ and a half-plane. In general, those will intersect in *two* rays, not one.

Comment: What should be the form of the two solution I could get then?